# Pyinstaller's .exe file closes immediately

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a working python package that's a CLI tool and I wanted to convert it into a single `.exe` file to upload it to other package managers so I used Pyinstaller. After building the `.exe` file with this command:

```
pyinstaller -c --log-level=DEBUG main.py 2> build.txt --onefile --exclude-module=pytest --add-data "src;src"
```

I double-clicked the .exe file but it closed immediately but in that split second, I saw the expected output which is supposed to be the command-line interface so the .exe does work but not entirely.

**main.py**

```
from src.Categorize_CLI.__main__ import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**.spec file**

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('src', 'src')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=['pytest'],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

**Update**

I got it working by dragging the main.exe file to a open command prompt and then pressed enter and it worked, and I got an error:

```
RuntimeError: 'package' is not installed. Try passing 'package_name' instead.
[15592] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: They are detected as a virus, they probably get deleted after a few tries right?

Comment: What I recommend you is using [Nuitka package](https://nuitka.net/) because it helps with your files not being detected as a virus and it has pretty much the same commands as `Pyinstaller`, just read the documentation so you don't mess anything up.

Comment: I ran the .exe file a couple times but it didn't get deleted. I will check out `Nuitka` hopefully that will solve my problem

Comment: Is your package name in the `datas` field in the spec file? I only see one. DId you try compiling to a folder first as the docs suggest? Also pause the anti virus for testing

Comment: @medic17 No that's the src folder which is outside the top level module `Categorize_CLI`. I added `src` folder as data because of a previous import error

Comment: I disabled the antivirus and I got the program to work but I have to run this command to make it work: `\path\to\exe [options] [commands]`

Comment: If you add `input()` to the end of the script does it work as expected?

Comment: No it results in the same behaviour

Comment: is the only problem now that you need to first open a terminal?

Comment: So now it works and it does exactly what I need it to do but I have to run this command: `path\to\main.exe [command]` for it to work, since its an exe file shouldn't it install after clicking on the exe file twice?

Comment: I updated my answer to better explain installing. Please add a comment there if you understand. If it helped you please accept as answer

Comment: So now can I just upload this .exe file to winget?

Comment: Yes you can. Make sure you meet all other requirements for winget (e. g. manifest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the script ran to end of file to fast for you to see. You can confirm this by opening your terminal (cmd/poweshell in windows) and running your program like any other CLI tool.

```
cd path\to\exe
./exe -arguments
```

Since you launched it from an allready opened terminal it won't close when the script ends.

If this is the problem you can solve it by adding

```py
input("Continue...") # wait for user
```

*Update*

As @BokiX says `pyinstaller` can cause false positives with anti virus software. Try a diffrent one e.g. nuikta:

```py
pip install Nuikta

python -m nuikta main.py
```

**installing python programs vs tradtitional programs**

A tradtitional program installer is usualy a fancy zip file with some additianal feautures to setup a program for the relevant system it's on (e.g. make registry changes, download additianal files).

A python program is just a python script that was "frozen" in state so it can run *independently* on a system without *python* or it's dependencies. once you have an `exe` it should just run without needing to be "installed".

**using console programs**
A console program is a program that is made to be exicuted from a terminal. In modern use these are usualy so they can be run by a script or someone who finds typing is faster than using a GUI.

Comment: The main.exe file got detected as `Trojan:Win32/Wacatac.B!ml` and then got deleted

Answer (score 1):

Run the code in the cmd and not by clicking the exe

A pyinstaller exe "usually" closes when 1 - Theres an error in the code , 2 - The code execution finished , closes after displaying the output

Also as BokiX stated , pyinstaller exe's often get false flagged as malicious , so maybe add an exception to your anti virus.

Comment: The main.exe file got detected as `Trojan:Win32/Wacatac.B!ml` and then got deleted

Comment: Add an exception to your anti virus so it does not delete

Comment: I disabled the antivirus and I got the program to work but I have to run this command to make it work: `\path\to\exe [options] [commands]`

Comment: Then thats something in your exe , cant help with that